# Sending request to API using react

Tags: reactjs, jsx

**I am new to React,and I don't know to to send request to an API using react and how to feed the response data to my component.**

**shop.jsx**

```js
import React from 'react';
import './shop.css';

class Shop extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div class="blog-post">
                <div class="blog-post_img">
                    <img src="shop.jpg" alt=""></img>
                </div>
                <div class="blog-post_info">
                    <h1 class="blog-post_title">{this.props.name}</h1>
                    <p class="blog-post_text">
                        {this.props.address}
                    </p>
                    <p class="blog-post_text">
                        {this.props.mobile}
                    </p>
                    <a href="#" class="blog-post_cta">Visit Shop</a>
    
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Shop;
```

**shops.jsx**

```js
import React from 'react';
import './shops.css';
import Shop from './shop'

class Shops extends React.Component{
    constructor() {
        super()
      }
      componentWillMount() {
        this.getData()
      }
      getData() {
        // create a new XMLHttpRequest
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    
        // get a callback when the server responds
        xhr.addEventListener('load', () => {
          // update the state of the component with the result here
          console.log(xhr.responseText)
        })
        // open the request with the verb and the url
        xhr.open('GET','http://localhost:5000/api/shops/allShops')
        // send the request
        xhr.send()
      }
    render(){
        const shopjsx = this.state.shops.map((item, i) =>(<Shop name={item.shopname} address={item.address} mobile={item.phoneNumber}/>));
        return(
            <div id="container">
                {shopjsx}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Shops;
```

**I know that my code for shops.jsx is wrong, what I want is that, I want to make request to my API, and want that when I get the data from API, I need to put that data in shop.jsx components.**

**Request to the API should be sent like this:**
GET http://localhost:5000/api/shops/allShops
Authorization: Bearer dcbjdsbchjedjcvdfcvfcjdfvcjfdjcvfdjcjdfjchjdfchbdfcjhdfhcbj

**From response I need only: shopname, phoneNumber, address**

**response from my API looks like this:**

```
fetchedShops: Array(78)
0:
created_at: "2020-06-18T07:50:42.356Z"
isActive: true
isApproved: false
isOpen: true
isPhoneVerified: false
name: "kalluHalwai"
phoneNumber: "9829648597"
plans: []
timingRules: {lunchCancellationDeadline: 1030, dinnerCancellationDeadline: 1730}
updated_at: "2020-06-18T07:50:42.356Z"
__v: 0
_id: "5eeb1cd295c9523da0a99ee0"
__proto__: Object
1:
created_at: "2020-06-18T09:30:28.985Z"
isActive: true
isApproved: false
isOpen: true
isPhoneVerified: false
name: "kalluHalwai"
phoneNumber: "9829648597"
plans: []
timingRules: {lunchCancellationDeadline: 1030, dinnerCancellationDeadline: 1730}
updated_at: "2020-06-18T09:30:28.985Z"
__v: 0
_id: "5eeb3434e2662738509ebf8a"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: sharing your auth token in here is not a good idea

Comment: its on localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few changes required to make your code working:

- set up `this.state` in class constructor. This property will store data from API and be used during rendering
- use [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) instead of [`componentWillMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount) . The `componentDidMount` method runs after first render of the component. It is a good place to add requesting 3rd party for data.
- use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) to get the data from API instead of `XMLHttpRequest`. It makes code clearer and easier to use.

Here is working example:

```js
class Shops extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      shops: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // replace with correct token and URL: http://localhost:5000/api/shops/allShops
    const TOKEN = "";
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {
      method: "get",
      headers: new Headers({
        Authorization: `Bearer ${TOKEN}`
      })
    })
      .then(response => response.status === 200 ? response.json() : [])
      .then(data => this.setState({ shops: data }))
      .catch(err => console.log("Error", err));
  }

  render() {
    const shops =
      this.state.shops.length > 0 ?
        this.state.shops.map(item => (
          <Shop name={item.id} address={item.title} mobile={item.body} />
        ))
        : <span>No data</span>;
    return <div id="container">{shops}</div>;
  }
}

class Shop extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="blog-post">
        <div class="blog-post_img">
          <img src="shop.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="blog-post_info">
          <h1 class="blog-post_title">{this.props.name}</h1>
          <p class="blog-post_text">{this.props.address}</p>
          <p class="blog-post_text">{this.props.mobile}</p>
          <a href="https://google.com" class="blog-post_cta">
            Visit Shop
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Shops />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

It requests [publicly available API](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) so data is different and no token is required (I add setting the `Authorization` header, but it is not used by the API).

Comment: getting this error -TypeError: this.state.shops.map is not a function

Comment: Do you get this error while using the above example or your own?

Comment: I've updated the anwser and make it more error resilient. When there is no data it shows "No data", otherwise shows data. Check if it works for you now.

Comment: i am getting an empty array in response

Comment: i should have got response like this : {
  "response": [
    {
      "timingRules": {
        "lunchCancellationDeadline": 1030,
        "dinnerCancellationDeadline": 1730
      },

Comment: when i use console.log(this.state.shops); then in console i am getting empty arrays two times and then at last getting the real response, pls solve my problme

Comment: Update your question with response you expect from API.

Comment: I have updated the question that what response i get normally when i use my api, i only want to use shopname,addess and phone number of all the shops from given response

Comment: please help noe

Comment: Replace my `fetch/then/catch` with `fetch(/* write correct request to your API here */).then(console.log).catch(err => console.log('Error', err));` and paste console log you get (here maybe: https://pastebin.com/?). I suppose there is a problem with response you get from API.